# what is wrong in this quick sort code

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

what is wrong with this quick sort code I an getting wrong output for certain input cases :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void quick_sort(int A[], int start, int end) {
    int pIndex;

    if (start < end) {
        pIndex=partion(A,start,end);
        quick_sort(A,start,pIndex-1);
        quick_sort(A,pIndex+1,end);
    }

}

int partion(int A[], int start, int end) {
    int i, temp, pIndex = start;
    int pivot = A[end];

    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= pivot) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pIndex];
            A[pIndex] = A[i];
            pIndex++;
        }
    }

    temp = A[pIndex];
    A[pIndex] = A[end];
    A[end] = temp;
    return pIndex;
}

int main() {
    int A[100], size, i;

    scanf("%d\n", &size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    quick_sort(A, 0, size-1);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I getting wrong output for following input:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGNpV.jpg)

what should I do to get the sorting right in ascending order

Comment: It doesn't sort at [all](http://ideone.com/tCoTjM).

Comment: Please do not add text input and output as images. (Unless you really got this JPEG as output, which would be quite surprising.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really mean `A[pIndex]=A[i];` or it should be `A[pIndex]=temp;` - that's supposed to be a swapping operation.

Comment: Really thanks for the help. Sorry for the dumb post I realized my mistake